# Why would I randomly start receiving the error "MSP error: channel doesn't exist" Hyperledger Fabric for an existing channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running three peer nodes on HLF v1.3. To interact with Fabric, I'm using the JS SDK. Approximately a day after spinning up the containers, installing, instantiating, and continuously running test invocations, I start receiving the following errors:

In the API container logs:

```
[2018-11-12 13:59:15.131] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - invoke chaincode proposal was bad
[2018-11-12 13:59:15.131] [ERROR] invoke-chaincode - Failed to invoke chaincode. Cause: Failed to send proposal and receive all good ProposalResponse
```

On the corresponding `peer` container logs:

```
peer0.1.y9mur3rk78x7@master0    | 2018-11-12 13:59:15.131 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> WARN 627982 channel [mychannel]: MSP error: channel doesn't exist
```

Given that invocation works successfully every second with our test runner up until this point, **what could cause HLF to suddenly lose/delete a channel and start returning these errors**?

For more backstory, these containers are running in docker swarm mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the docker logs command,for example, 'docker logs peer0.org1.example.com', you can check all logs for ca, couchdb, peer, orderer. I believe you can find some reason. If you are using shell script to run, sometimes sleep is helpful at some point.

Specifically, after creating channel, you need to set sleep for a moment. Default sleep time is 15 seconds in example fabric-dev-server configuration. I am using 3 seconds, but it depends on your hardware and business network.